# Knockout updating an array of checkboxes from list of values

Tags: knockout.js

I have a form which adds a new person record and can also edit their record.

So, when it is a new record the form presents a list of unchecked checkboxes which correspond to their qualifications. They save back to the database with no trouble.

When I want to edit the person data I can get hold of their qualifications as a delimited list of qualification ids. I therefore want to check the appropriate checkboxes on the form.

I guess there is a mapping / update function required to update the obsevable checkbox array with the data for the person.

I have set up a basic [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikertjones/GS2aJ/2/) but with the important bit missing.

I wonder of anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve your problem in a different way than the one I posted? Would you mind sharing it if it's the case?

Answer (score 0):

The following custom binding was originally posted by another user, RPNiemeyer, but at the moment I cannot retrieve the answer. 
Anyway you can find it following:

The custom binding is called "checkedWithInit" and the checked attribute of the HTML element here is conveniently set as true just to be clear:

```
<input id="yourId" type="checkbox" value="yourValue" data-bind="checkedWithInit: yourInitialStateVariable" checked="true" />
```

The custom binding code is an "override" of the element's "init" event handler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkedWithInit = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (element.checked) {
            //if it is an array then push this value to it
            if (value.push) {
                value.push(element.value);                 
            } else { //otherwise, just write the value
                if (ko.isWriteableObservable(value)) {
                    value(element.checked);   
                }
            }
        }
        //run the real checked binding's init function
        ko.bindingHandlers.checked.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, context);
        },
        //always run the checked bindings update function
        update: ko.bindingHandlers.checked.update
    };
```

I hope this helps,

Valerio